# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in

Tags: php, sql

Ошибка в поисковом запросе.

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['query'])) { 
    $search_result = search ($_POST['query']); 
    echo $search_result; 
}
else {
    echo "Запрос пустой!";
}
?>





    function search ($query) { 
    require_once "../includes/config.php";
    $query = trim($query); 
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);

    if (!empty($query)) 
    { 
        if (strlen($query) < 3) {
            $text = '<p>Слишком короткий поисковый запрос.</p>';
        } else if (strlen($query) > 128) {
            $text = '<p>Слишком длинный поисковый запрос.</p>';
        } else { 


$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT news_id, title, text FROM `news` WHERE `text` LIKE '%$query%' OR `title` LIKE '%$query%'");




  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
      <?php  
    echo $row['title'];
    ?>
    <?php 
      echo '<br>'.$row['text'].'<br>';
  }     

    return $text; 
} 
}
}




<?php 

$config = array(

'title' => 'name',
'db'=> array(

'server' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'dbname' => 'name_db'
)
);



 require "db.php";
```

Comment: А что такое `$connection`, где вы его объявляете ? Вообще ошибка дословно говорит, что первый параметр NULL, значит вы просто соединение с БД не открыли

Comment: $connection объявляю в отдельном файле и подключаю его в начале каждой страницы. Я ведь не первый раз запросы так делал. Все нормально работало.

Comment: Я не вижу в приведенном вами коде include и других признаков включения каких либо других файлов

Comment: И это конечно хорошо, что вы уже используете mysqli. Но при этом вы почему то пользуетесь mysql_real_escape_string() которая из расширения mysql и уже начинает удаляться из php. скоро этой финкции не будет нигде. Не используйте ее. Вместо этого используйте подготавливаемые запросы и привязку значений http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Добавил свое подключение в код.

Comment: NULL вернуло, то есть подключение отсутствовало. Вставил код подключения в саму функцию - все заработало. Так получается что require_once  не подключало файл в функцию? Почему?

Comment: Ну я ведь подключал файл в саму функцию. Насколько мне известно инструкция require_once заменяет инструкцию на содержимое файла.

Comment: Обычно необходимые файлы подключают в начале скрипта и вне функций/классов.